# Natural deduction: negation of quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

How can I show that $\lnot \exists x P(x) \vdash \forall x\lnot P(x)$
?

Because I want to show: 
$\lnot \exists x (P(x) \lor R(x)) \vdash \forall x \lnot R(x)$

My idea: maybe a proof by contradiction would work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $¬∃xP(x)⊢∀x¬P(x)$, it is enough to assume $P(x)$ :

1) $¬∃xP(x)$ --- premise

2) $P(x)$ --- assumed [a]

3) $∃xP(x)$ --- from 2) by $∃$-introduction

4) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 3)

5) $¬P(x)$ --- from 2) and 4) by $¬$-introduction, discharging [a]

> 6) $∀x¬P(x)$ --- from 5), by $∀$-introduction.